# How to Inject a .NET managed DLL into another .NET process

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection

Well, what i want to do is Injecting a C# DLL into another C# process,
then from outside (lets call it "the injector") call a method of that dll, all of this from c#.

Is it possible?

How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[EasyHook](https://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html) is your friend.

You can use the remote hooking functionality it provides to load a managed dll into target process, and invoke methods with .NET remoting.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you mean .net libraries' dlls. Because c# is programming language not a process. In .net projects, dll's comes from .net runtime libraries. In order to load dll's in runtime you can use:
`Assembly.LoadFrom("example.dll");`

Comment: Thats not what i mean, i want from my program (process 1, C#) inject a dll into another process (process 2, C#) and call a method of that dll from my process 1